# MPAndroidchart YAxis Labels gets extra, unnecessary padding on YAxis formatter change

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

When I'm adding a new set with the different data type (%) I'm updating right axis formatter to a different one. After that, I'm updating LineData and calling invalidate() on the chart.
Seems pretty standard case, but the effect is like below:
[image: [https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/157498/3183982/4bvTKP8iwHO29ap/didd.png](screenshot)]

here is the code: (in scope of class which inherits from LineChart)

```
    override fun setData(data: LineData, xAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?, leftAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?, rightAxisFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter?) {


    xAxisFormatter?.let { xAxis.valueFormatter = it }
    leftAxisFormatter?.let { axisLeft.valueFormatter = it }
    rightAxisFormatter?.let { axisRight.valueFormatter = it }

    this.data = data
    invalidate()
}
```

The bottom one is one after the update. Can spot the right spacing difference? it's pretty annoying and breaks UX :(
Any idea why?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that this extra spacing is calculated by lib. It goes from maksimum possible width of label in scope of entire chart. In this case, max value at chart is 732000, and % label with that value would look like "73200000%" - it would take a lot of space, so there is a big spacing... Another thing that this value is on the other axis, but i think it is a library bug.

I handled it by updating right axis label formatter, to handle big numbers in smart way, so calculated string could be shorter. It helped a little.